# Vue - how can i style an Element-UI datatable?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, element-ui

I'm trying to add an [element ui datatable](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table) to my project, but i'm having an hard time  figuring how to change the color of the table. Here is what i have:

```
<template>
  <el-table
    :data="tableData.filter(data => !search || data.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()))"
    style="width: 100%">
    <el-table-column
      label="Date"
      prop="date">
    </el-table-column>
    <el-table-column
      label="Name"
      prop="name">
    </el-table-column>
    <el-table-column
      align="right">
      <template slot="header" slot-scope="scope">
        <el-input
          v-model="search"
          size="mini"
          placeholder="Type to search"/>
      </template>
      <template slot-scope="scope">
        <el-button
          size="mini"
          @click="handleEdit(scope.$index, scope.row)">Edit</el-button>
        <el-button
          size="mini"
          type="danger"
          @click="handleDelete(scope.$index, scope.row)">Delete</el-button>
      </template>
    </el-table-column>
  </el-table>
</template>

<style>

.thead {
  color: red;
}
.el-table thead {
  color: red;
}

</style>

<script>

export default {

  props:{


  },

  data() {
      return {
        tableData: [{
          date: '2016-05-03',
          name: 'Tom',
          address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
        }, {
          date: '2016-05-02',
          name: 'John',
          address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
        }, {
          date: '2016-05-04',
          name: 'Morgan',
          address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
        }, {
          date: '2016-05-01',
          name: 'Jessy',
          address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
        }],

        search: '',
      }
    },

    methods: {
      handleEdit(index, row) {
        console.log(index, row.name);
      },
      handleDelete(index, row) {
        console.log(index, row.name);
      }
    },
  

}

</script>
```

Everything i tried here doesn't seem to have any effect on the table, nothing changes. I also tried with `background-color` or other classes, such as `.el-table` but nothing worked. Any kind of advice is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the table background color didn't work because the rows have a background color by default that shows on top.  The datatable provides [multiple props](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table#table-attributes) for styling or you could target the row directly in CSS.  In either case, it seems you'll need the `!important` modifier or it doesn't overwrite the default styles:

Option 1: Using a prop like `row-class-name`:

```html
<el-table
  row-class-name="myrow"
>
```

```css
.myrow {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

Option 2: Modifying the CSS directly using `tr` (or `td`, `th`, etc.)

```css
.el-table tr {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

(Or you could use a more specific selector to avoid the need for `!important` if modifying directly, if that matters to you.)

Comment: If i may ask, one last thing: so if i set it to red, the background of the rows is going to be red, but what i don't like is that between each row there is a white line separating the rows, is there any way to edit the color of that line too? I've been through the docs but didn't find any

Comment: That's being set on the `td`.  Try this:   `.el-table td { border-bottom: 0px !important; }`

Answer (score 1):

try deep selector

```
.variableName>>>.el-table{
  background-color: red !important;
}
.variableName/deep/.el-table{
  background-color: red !important;
}
```